# Haskell : Filter list for elements of second list

Tags: list, haskell

I am currently trying to filter a list , that consist of tuples of the form (String , Double), for a List that consists of Strings. If the tuple doesn't contain a String of the second list, it should be removed from the list of tuples. So far I came up with this:

```
test :: [ExamScore] -> String -> [ExamScore]
test a b = filter ((== b).fst) a
```

My current problem is to replace the String that is filtered for by a list of Strings. Thanks for your help! Please go easy on me, I'm a first year informatics student that hasn't coded anytime before.

Comment: please show an example call and its desired result.

Answer (score 0):

It's almost the same, just another filter function using [`elem`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.12.0.0/docs/Data-List.html#g:14):

```
test a b :: [ExamScore] -> [String] -> [ExamScore]
test a b = filter (\(s, _) -> elem s b) a
```

Or, if you're more into the composition style:

```
test a b = filter (flip elem b . fst) a
```

(It's worth noting that it's not the most efficient way, since `elem` is `O(N)` for lists, so depending on your case you may want to find a better structure for storing the keys.)

Comment: The inner parentheses in the second definition are unneeded.